# Проблема в шейдере при отрисовки

Tags: java, opengl, шейдеры, lwjgl

Продолжение к моей прошлой работе. Я продвинулся дальше. Я разобрался как определить находится ли точка внутри фрустума или нет. Сделал это так: просто вычислял расстояние до каждой из 6 плоскостей, если оно окажется отрицательным, то точка лежит не внутри фрустума. Реализовал это все во фрагментном шейдере.

Ниже реализация этого шейдера. В него передаю 6 квадратных матрицы размера 3  **A B C D E F** - каждая из них содержит 3 вершины плоскости. В шейдере был написан метод, который находит расстояние между точкой и плоскостью `distancePointPlane`. При запуске программы он независимо выделен ли полигон или нет отрисовывает цветом. С передачей координат вершин проблем не должно быть. Проблема на уровне вычисления в шейдере. Помогите.

Ниже шейдеры в них скорее всего и ошибка: 
В вершинный шейдер передаю

```
 vec4[6] planes - a b c d для 6 плоскостей.
out float[6] dis; - это расстояния, которые я передаю во фрагментный шейдер.

#version 330

layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPos;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 normal;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 texCoord;

out float[6] dis;
out vec3 normal_modelspace;
out vec3 vertex_modelspace;
out vec2 TexCoord;
out vec4 vertexColor;
uniform mat4 P;
uniform mat4 V;
uniform mat4 M;

uniform vec4[6] planes;


void main() {
    TexCoord = texCoord;
    vertex_modelspace = (M * vec4(vertexPos.xyz, 1.0)).xyz;
    vertexColor = vec4(0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    gl_Position = P * V * vec4(vertex_modelspace.xyz, 1.0);
    normal_modelspace = (M * vec4(normal.xyz, 1.0)).xyz;
    vec3 EyeDirection_cameraspace = vec3(0,0,0) - (V * M * vec4(vertexPos,1)).xyz;

     for(int i = 0;i<6;i++){
       float denom = sqrt(planes[0].x * planes[0].x + planes[0].y * planes[0].y + planes[0].z * planes[0].z);
       dis[i] = float((planes[0].x * vertex_modelspace.x + planes[0].y * vertex_modelspace.y + planes[0].z * vertex_modelspace.z + planes[0].w) / denom);
     }
}
```

**Фрагментный шейдер** 
здесь я в цикле проверяю расстояния для точки, если найдено отрицательное значение, то должно закрашиваться цветом.

```
#version 330 core

in vec3 normal_modelspace;
in vec3 vertex_modelspace;
in vec2 TexCoord;
in vec4 vertexColor;
in float[6] dis;
out vec4 color;

uniform vec3 light_worldspace;

uniform sampler2D ourTexture;

void main() {
  vec3 n = normalize(normal_modelspace);
  vec3 l = normalize(light_worldspace - vertex_modelspace);
  float cosTheta = clamp( dot( n, l), 0,1 );
  float ambient = 0.05;
    int i=0;
    while(i<6 && dis[i]<=0){
      i++;
    }
    if(i==6){
      color = texture(ourTexture, TexCoord);
    }
    else
      color = vertexColor;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не понятно суть вопроса. В чём проблема, что работает не так, как должно работать.

Comment: @Unick сейчас проблема другая как нарисовать селектирующий луч. чтобы он выглядел как точка

Comment: можно лучше луч рисовать как 3Д объект, а не рассчитывать в шейдере.

Comment: @Unick я так и делаю . но координаты селектирующего луча нужно находить. у меня никак не получается

Comment: если ваша текущая проблема не связана с этим вопросом, то следует задать новый вопрос. А вообще вам необходимо умножить координаты мышки, переведённые в интервал от [-1..1] на обратну матрицу проекции и обратную матрицу вида. Получив так 2 точке с разным Z вы сможете построить луч.

Comment: @Unick я так и делал. но почему то не получается